# Unity3D, build PNG from Panel of a Unity.UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, unity3d-ui

Think about any Unity.UI `Canvas` you might have.

Imagine a typical `Panel` on that Canvas. Say it happens to contain some images, maybe some Text and so on.

It would be very handy if you could turn that panel (only the panel) in to a screenshot: a Texture2D or PNG.

The only thing I can think of is just using `ReadPixels` and figuring out the area of the `Panel` in question on the screen (and actually that is pretty tricky); and that only works if the panel happens to be square and not rotated at an angle.

You'd think, there should be a way to render one Panel, or at least, one whole canvas?  I can find nothing.

[image]

[image]

In the example, make the pink Panel a PNG image.  Ouch.

(Obviously, if anyone has a solution that does merely "the whole Canvas", rather than one Panel, of course even that is admirable.)

Comment: This actually sounds complicated. Taking screenshot is one thing but taking screenshot of a panel is another story. When your say screenshot of a panel do you mean UI that is a child of the panel?

Comment: Do you mean **all** UI in the panel.?

Comment: Right - a panel, that is to say a `CanvasRenderer`, colloquially known as a 'panel' when you make one using the menu or context menu "create -> UI" .... image added!

Comment: Oh ok. I will see if I can pull this off.

Comment: Just posted my solution with a working example. It gets the work done.I spend time trying to remove bugs. If you find a bug, you can fix and update my answer.Your job now is to optimize....

Comment: @Programmer incredible, am checking it out now!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code below can take picture of a Canvas. Canvas must be attached the Object you are passing into it. The only function to call is  `void takeScreenShot(Canvas canvasPanel, SCREENSHOT_TYPE screenShotType = SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, bool createNewInstance = true)`

`SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT` parameter will take picture of **images** and **texts**.

`SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_ONLY` parameter will only take picture of **images**. Every texts on the screen will be excluded. You can use this for security reason to remove texts and just show graphics only.

`SCREENSHOT_TYPE.TEXT_ONLY` parameter will take picture of **Texts** only.

How to use. Create a GameObject, attach the CanvasScreenShot script to it. Subscribe to `CanvasScreenShot.OnPictureTaken(byte[] pngArray)`;, then call `screenShot.takeScreenShot(canvasToSreenShot, SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, false);`

**Complete Code:**

Your `test.cs` script:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvasToSreenShot;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Subscribe
        CanvasScreenShot.OnPictureTaken += receivePNGScreenShot;
        CanvasScreenShot screenShot = GameObject.Find("GameObject").GetComponent<CanvasScreenShot>();

        //take ScreenShot(Image and Text)
        //screenShot.takeScreenShot(canvasToSreenShot, SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, false);
        //take ScreenShot(Image only)
        screenShot.takeScreenShot(canvasToSreenShot, SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_ONLY, false);
        //take ScreenShot(Text only)
        // screenShot.takeScreenShot(canvasToSreenShot, SCREENSHOT_TYPE.TEXT_ONLY, false);

    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        //Un-Subscribe
        CanvasScreenShot.OnPictureTaken -= receivePNGScreenShot;
    }

    void receivePNGScreenShot(byte[] pngArray)
    {
        Debug.Log("Picture taken");

        //Do Something With the Image (Save)
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/CanvasScreenShot.png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, pngArray);
        Debug.Log(path);
    }

}
```

The `CanvasScreenShot.cs` script:

```
public class CanvasScreenShot : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*
 CanvasScreenShot by programmer.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555521/unity3d-build-png-from-panel-of-a-unity-ui#36555521
 http://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer
 */

    //Events
    public delegate void takePictureHandler(byte[] pngArray);
    public static event takePictureHandler OnPictureTaken;

    private GameObject duplicatedTargetUI;
    private Image[] allImages;
    private Text[] allTexts;

    //Store all other canvas that will be disabled and re-anabled after screenShot
    private Canvas[] allOtherCanvas;

    //takes Screenshot
    public void takeScreenShot(Canvas canvasPanel, SCREENSHOT_TYPE screenShotType = SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, bool createNewInstance = true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(_takeScreenShot(canvasPanel, screenShotType, createNewInstance));
    }

    private IEnumerator _takeScreenShot(Canvas canvasPanel, SCREENSHOT_TYPE screenShotType = SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT, bool createNewInstance = true)
    {
        //Get Visible Canvas In the Scene
        allOtherCanvas = getAllCanvasInScene(false);

        //Hide all the other Visible Canvas except the one that is passed in as parameter(Canvas we want to take Picture of)
        showCanvasExcept(allOtherCanvas, canvasPanel, false);
        //Reset the position so that both UI will be in the-same place if we make the duplicate a child
        resetPosAndRot(gameObject);

        //Check if we should operate on the original image or make a duplicate of it
        if (createNewInstance)
        {
            //Duplicate the Canvas we want to take Picture of
            duplicatedTargetUI = duplicateUI(canvasPanel.gameObject, "ScreenShotUI");
            //Make this game object the parent of the Canvas
            duplicatedTargetUI.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);

            //Hide the orginal Canvas we want to take Picture of
            showCanvas(canvasPanel, false);
        }
        else
        {
            //No duplicate. Use original GameObject
            //Make this game object the parent of the Canvas
            canvasPanel.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        }

        RenderMode defaultRenderMode;

        //Change the duplicated Canvas to RenderMode to overlay
        Canvas duplicatedCanvas = null;
        if (createNewInstance)
        {
            duplicatedCanvas = duplicatedTargetUI.GetComponent<Canvas>();
            defaultRenderMode = duplicatedCanvas.renderMode;
            duplicatedCanvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        }
        else
        {
            defaultRenderMode = canvasPanel.renderMode;
            canvasPanel.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        }


        if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT)
        {
            //No Action Needed
        }
        else if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_ONLY)
        {
            if (createNewInstance)
            {
                //Get all images on the duplicated visible Canvas
                allTexts = getAllTextsFromCanvas(duplicatedTargetUI, false);
                //Hide those images
                showTexts(allTexts, false);
            }
            else
            {
                //Get all images on the duplicated visible Canvas
                allTexts = getAllTextsFromCanvas(canvasPanel.gameObject, false);
                //Hide those images
                showTexts(allTexts, false);
            }
        }
        else if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.TEXT_ONLY)
        {
            if (createNewInstance)
            {
                //Get all images on the duplicated visible Canvas
                allImages = getAllImagesFromCanvas(duplicatedTargetUI, false);
                //Hide those images
                showImages(allImages, false);
            }
            else
            {
                //Get all images on the duplicated visible Canvas
                allImages = getAllImagesFromCanvas(canvasPanel.gameObject, false);
                //Hide those images
                showImages(allImages, false);
            }
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////Finally Take ScreenShot///////////////////////////////
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        //Get Image from screen
        screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        screenImage.Apply();

        //Convert to png
        byte[] pngBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

        /*FOR TESTING/DEBUGGING PURPOSES ONLY. COMMENT THIS
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/CanvasScreenShot.png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, pngBytes);
        Debug.Log(path);*/

        //Notify functions that are subscribed to this event that picture is taken then pass in image bytes as png
        if (OnPictureTaken != null)
        {
            OnPictureTaken(pngBytes);
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////RE-ENABLE OBJECTS

        //Change the duplicated Canvas RenderMode back to default Value
        if (createNewInstance)
        {
            duplicatedCanvas.renderMode = defaultRenderMode;
        }
        else
        {
            canvasPanel.renderMode = defaultRenderMode;
        }
        //Un-Hide all the other Visible Canvas except the one that is passed in as parameter(Canvas we want to take Picture of)
        showCanvas(allOtherCanvas, true);
        if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_AND_TEXT)
        {
            //No Action Needed
        }
        else if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.IMAGE_ONLY)
        {
            //Un-Hide those images
            showTexts(allTexts, true);
        }
        else if (screenShotType == SCREENSHOT_TYPE.TEXT_ONLY)
        {
            //Un-Hide those images
            showImages(allImages, true);
        }

        //Un-hide the orginal Canvas we want to take Picture of
        showCanvas(canvasPanel, true);

        if (createNewInstance)
        {
            //Destroy the duplicated GameObject
            Destroy(duplicatedTargetUI, 1f);
        }
        else
        {
            //Remove the Canvas as parent 
            canvasPanel.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }

    private GameObject duplicateUI(GameObject parentUICanvasOrPanel, string newOBjectName)
    {
        GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(parentUICanvasOrPanel);
        tempObj.name = newOBjectName;
        return tempObj;
    }


    private Image[] getAllImagesFromCanvas(GameObject canvasParentGameObject, bool findDisabledCanvas = false)
    {
        Image[] tempImg = canvasParentGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(findDisabledCanvas);
        if (findDisabledCanvas)
        {
            return tempImg;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Image> canvasList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Image>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempImg.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tempImg[i].enabled)
                {
                    canvasList.Add(tempImg[i]);
                }
            }
            return canvasList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private Text[] getAllTextsFromCanvas(GameObject canvasParentGameObject, bool findDisabledCanvas = false)
    {
        Text[] tempImg = canvasParentGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(findDisabledCanvas);
        if (findDisabledCanvas)
        {
            return tempImg;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Text> canvasList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Text>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempImg.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tempImg[i].enabled)
                {
                    canvasList.Add(tempImg[i]);
                }
            }
            return canvasList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private Canvas[] getAllCanvasFromCanvas(Canvas canvasParentGameObject, bool findDisabledCanvas = false)
    {
        Canvas[] tempImg = canvasParentGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(findDisabledCanvas);
        if (findDisabledCanvas)
        {
            return tempImg;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Canvas> canvasList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Canvas>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempImg.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tempImg[i].enabled)
                {
                    canvasList.Add(tempImg[i]);
                }
            }
            return canvasList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    //Find Canvas.
    private Canvas[] getAllCanvasInScene(bool findDisabledCanvas = false)
    {
        Canvas[] tempCanvas = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Canvas>();
        if (findDisabledCanvas)
        {
            return tempCanvas;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Canvas> canvasList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Canvas>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempCanvas.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tempCanvas[i].enabled)
                {
                    canvasList.Add(tempCanvas[i]);
                }
            }
            return canvasList.ToArray();
        }
    }

    //Disable/Enable Images
    private void showImages(Image[] imagesToDisable, bool enableImage = true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            imagesToDisable[i].enabled = enableImage;
        }
    }

    //Disable/Enable Texts
    private void showTexts(Text[] imagesToDisable, bool enableTexts = true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            imagesToDisable[i].enabled = enableTexts;
        }
    }


    //Disable/Enable Canvas
    private void showCanvas(Canvas[] canvasToDisable, bool enableCanvas = true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < canvasToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            canvasToDisable[i].enabled = enableCanvas;
        }
    }


    //Disable/Enable one canvas
    private void showCanvas(Canvas canvasToDisable, bool enableCanvas = true)
    {
        canvasToDisable.enabled = enableCanvas;
    }

    //Disable/Enable Canvas Except
    private void showCanvasExcept(Canvas[] canvasToDisable, Canvas ignoreCanvas, bool enableCanvas = true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < canvasToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!(canvasToDisable[i] == ignoreCanvas))
            {
                canvasToDisable[i].enabled = enableCanvas;
            }
        }
    }

    //Disable/Enable Canvas Except
    private void showCanvasExcept(Canvas[] canvasToDisable, Canvas[] ignoreCanvas, bool enableCanvas = true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < canvasToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ignoreCanvas.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!(canvasToDisable[i] == ignoreCanvas[j]))
                {
                    canvasToDisable[i].enabled = enableCanvas;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Reset Position
    private void resetPosAndRot(GameObject posToReset)
    {
        posToReset.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        posToReset.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
    }

}

public enum SCREENSHOT_TYPE
{
    IMAGE_AND_TEXT, IMAGE_ONLY, TEXT_ONLY
}
```

Comment: When you finish testing you let me if there is any problem

Comment: this seems to work great.  I don't think anything else can be asked for!  great stuff!

Comment: Glad I was  able to help. Speaking about your comment about bringing the old code back, it is gone. I selected it and deleted all of them and started over again with the code above, after I thought performance is a requirement.I don't think I will ever be able to get it back because I've closed visual studio and re-opened it. Un-do is gone.....

Comment: I know this is really old but here goes - since you are passing the whole canvas to the script, how does it save only a specific part of the canvas to the image? Also, I tried this script and the screenshot that gets saved, also has a sprite in it which is part of the scene but not on the canvas. I am using unity 5.3.2. Any help is truly appreciated as I have been breaking my head on this for long.

Comment: @TheDevilsFire That's not a bug. When I wrote this, I only intended it to exclude other UI canvas. I did not make it to exclude sprite or 3D objects/Mesh Renderer but you can implement that yourself.All this code does is to hide other Objects, take picture, un-hide them then return the picture taken. You can extend it to include sprite and 3D objects/Mesh Renderer.

Comment: @Programmer Alright - will do that but the other issue is how do i specify only a part of the canvas that needs to be saved and not save the whole canvas?

Comment: @TheDevilsFire This was made for Canvas. So a canvas in the middle or the corner of the screen can have their picture taken without other ui in other canvas.  To do what you are asking, you will have to re-write the whole script. You can do it if  you understand how it works. It hides other ui from other canvas, takes a picture, unhide them and return the picture taken. You can easily implement that for your needs. There are many important functions that are re-usable in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick stab at it since I can't find any official easy way to do it.

I have no idea how performance intensive this would be since I haven't tried it.

Add a camera, pointed at the UI panel to get a straight on shot. Render the camera to a texture, with only that panel being rendered on the camera, destroy the camera.

[Then encode the texture to a png](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html).

1. This could be horribly expensive.
2. It would also render the rest of the screen unless you size the
   camera to the panel, and even then if the panel isn't a square or
   rectangle you will get part of the game/skybox/background color in
   the shot.
3. It could just plain not work

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into it deeply, but I assume it is impossible to render a Panel without rendering its parent Canvas. I'm also assuming that you don't want to do this every frame, but only on specific occasions.

In that context, here's what I would try:

- Have a second Canvas with RenderMode "Screen Space - Camera". This allows you to specify the camera used to render this Canvas.
- Have a dedicated Camera to render your second Canvas.
- Give the Camera a script which handles OnPreCull and OnPostRender
- OnPreCull, attach the target Panel to your secondary Canvas. OnPostRender, reattach it to where it was before (I'm so... so sorry)
- Let the secondary Camera render onto a RenderTexture
- ReadPixels, Apply, EncodeToPNG, voila

Of course there are lots of details unspecified, like sizes and positions and whatever. But having dedicated Canvas and Camera should allow all of this to be figured out and setup correctly without messing stuff up.

Comment: "but only on specific occasions.", right certainly - only as a one off.  I will study your method!

Comment: Oh, it might be that OnPreRender is already too late to have the Panel actually included in the rendering. I will change my answer to suggest OnPreCull.

Comment: I think the key insight might be that, essentially, you need another camera with a duplicate of the panel in question (which after all is not that hard to organize).  perhaps that is the KISS solution.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I worked on this yesterday this was the first idea that came to my head. Mine was slightly different. I tried to duplicate the gameobject, create a new camera then move the ui and the camera to another position and take picture. That didn't work because the UI was moving but the camera refused to move with the UI. I tried to  use Layer and culling mask but there were too many problems I ran into and you have to create a new layer from the Editor for it to work. You can't create a layer from code....  I want something simple. Finally I got it to work. I am improving it before posting.

Comment: Although the code is longer than stackoverflow source code.

Comment: that is a brilliant idea to use **Layers** I just didn't think of it.  I mean it is fine if you "have to have" a layer in the project for the purpose, that's great.  Great thinking!!!  @Programmer

Comment: Actually you don't have to create Layers at all, a layer is nothing more than a value for GameObject's layer field, in the range of 0 to 31. Just set it to any free value. Then simply set Camera's layerMask to 1 << (layer) and you should be all good.

Comment: Lol I remember that tag is something you can't create by code not layer. My bad. There is a problem with unity UI. The layer stuff doesn't work with it unless you change the Render Mode of the canvas. So this means you have to loop through all enabled canvas in the scene and change each Render Mode then put the main camera in each canvas's "`Render Camera`" property in other for culling to work. Until this is fixed for the UI, I don't think it will be fast.

Comment: note .... ***speed is NOT a requirement*** here.  it's very much something like, imagine the end-user can assemble a little image (perhaps with text etc), and then click "Generate PNG!"  (imagine say emailing it to themselves).  so anything you guys have is great!

Comment: @JoeBlow didn't know that. Thought speed is a requirement and had to delete my first code that worked but slow.

Comment: hmm, maybe you should bring that back as well!  :)