# Transmit Small Data Between 2 iOS Phones on the Same Network in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, wireless, lan

I am trying to make a little wireless keyboard for a larger project that I am working on. I have 2 iPhones running `iOS 9` and I wish for them to send just small amounts of information between the 2 (just what is typed on the keyboard and maybe a bit of metadata). Both phones will be on the same network. What is a free way to do this just using Unity and C# (if there is one)? I would like the connections to be fairly fast, but since it is such a small amount of data that isn't my biggest concern.

Comment: If reliability isn't a concern i'd go for a simple WiFi broadcast packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a TCP server and Client. By using sockets instead of `Bluetooth`, this will also work in Android, pc and other platforms. Create a TCP server on one iPhone. Create a TCP client on the other iPhone and connect to the server phone. Send and receive data from each phone. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36526634/3785314) is a complete TCP server. You can modify the code a little bit to also create a client code.

Comment: It seems like that will work perfectly. Thanks! (2 days in a row).