# Unity socket program doesn't run

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I made a simple game in unity. I want this game to read data from socket as server. File named Socket.cs, creates a server and listens port 8000, if i run this file in visual studio, it works. I want to run this file when the unity game has started. The problem is here, game starts but socket.cs file hasn't been started. Socket.cs is placed on assets directory in unity game.

The code i used for socket server in c#: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16466625/

Could you help me please to start socket.cs file when the game has been started?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Unity does not have a `Main` function like a normal C# program. So putting a code in `public static void Main()` will not do anything. Unity uses `Start()` and other simliar functions as it's starting point not `Main()`.

> Socket.cs is placed on assets directory in unity game

Simply placing a script in the Asset Folder does not mean it will work. You have to instantiate the script from another Unity script or attach the Script to a GameObject.

Also even if the code worked  in Unity, Unity would freeze because the socket code is synchronous instead of asynchronous. It will block while reading or waiting for client to connect.

You should either make it with a `Thread` or use `asynchronous` socket.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/unity3d-c-sharp-plugin-to-act-as-a-socket-server/36526634#36526634) is complete Unity TCP server that works in Unity. It uses `Thread`.

I suggest you learn how Unity works. Learn the basic.

Comment: that is a very valuable link.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks. There have been over 4 questions about socket in Unity this week and that link solved all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Awesome explanation :)