# Trying to connect Emotiv Epoc Control Panel to a Java environment (Unity 3D)

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, sdk

Is this challenging and where do I begin?

I have Unity 3D and the Xavier Control Panel for Emotiv. On the Emotiv website there is a wrapper for Unity 3D but I would like to try and connect my control panel to a game myself. I'm sorry for the vagueness but I really do not know where to begin, my Java knowledge is low but am willing to learn.

Thanks!!

Comment: Not a proper question for SO. Please read site guidelines for asking good questions

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses C# and Javascript/Unityscript not Java. Maybe you meant Javascript? Anyways, since you refused to use the paid [wrapper](http://emotiv.com/product/unity3d-support-pack/) from Emotiv,you can make yours from scratch using TCP but that will take time.

Create a local TCP **server** on the Unity side, create a **client** on the emotive. Connect to the server, send and receive data from Unity to the client created on the other side with the help of the [Emotiv SDK](https://github.com/Emotiv/community-sdk).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I did mean JavaScript and its not that I refuse, I just want to learn how to do this myself - is using a server actually the easiest way? Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @KeelanEeles For this, you **must** use C# because of tcp socket. I am not sure they are available in Javascript. You will get more help if you use C# than javascript later on. And yes, server and client seems to be the easiest way I know about. Since you are new to unity and C#, this will take you forever. This is a server code http://stackoverflow.com/a/36526634/3785314 . You can make your client code from that.  This guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcCdOjlnNUM did his with socket/udp and it worked for him. Good luck!

Comment: @KeelanEeles If this answered your question you can go ahead and accept it as answer. Thanks.